# Getting the key with max value in a portion of a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary, its keys are `datetime.datetime` objects, such as:

```
a = {datetime(2018,1,1):1, datetime(2018,1,2):2, datetime(2018,1,3):3, ...}
```

I would like to get the key (date) with max value in a portion of this dictionary, such as between dates `2018-03-27` and `2018-04-17`.

What is the mosy pythonic way of achieving this?

Comment: From the duplicate: `max(a, key=a.get)`

Comment: I think the duplicate mark is not correct. The linked question is asking for the key with max value - yes - but this one adds the dictionary slice to it.

Comment: alwbtc, just to answer your question completely in a comment, you need to combine the linked answers (there is some remarks about performance in there, too) with slicing the key set:
`sliced_dict = {key, value for key, value in a.iteritems() if min_time <= key <= max_time }`
and
`max_key = max(sliced_dict, key=sliced_dict.get)`
with `min_time` and `max_time` being the border datetime objects.

Answer (score 3):

First select those items in the dictionary having a key between the required values, then find the one with the largest value:

```
from datetime import datetime

min_date = datetime(2018, 3, 27)
max_date = datetime(2018, 4, 17)

date = max((d[k], k) for k in d if min_date <= k <= max_date)[1]
```

This code creates a sequence of tuples containing the value and datetime (N.B. in that order) between `min_date` and `max_date`. Then it chooses the item from that sequence with the largest value. The required data is the second element in the resulting tuple.

Answer (score 2):

You can constrain the keys to that range of date using a *generator expression* and then take the one with the maximum value by passing the key as `a.get`:

```
date = max((k for k in a if datetime(2018, 03, 27) <= k <= datetime(2018, 04, 17)), 
            key=a.get)
```